# Polynomial curves $F(x,y)$ giving rise to loops

Tags: algebraic-topology, elliptic-curves, geometric-topology

I know that the cubic curve defined by [$F(x,y) = y^2 - x^3 - x^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_plane_curve) gives rise to a loop:

[image]

Is there a way to check if a cubic curve defined by $F(x,y) = y^2 + ay + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$ exhibits a loop? Can there be more than one loop?

What happens when we allow mixed terms, i.e. $F(x,y) = y^2 + ay + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e + fxy$ or even  $F(x,y) = y^2 + ay + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e + fxy + gx^2y + hxy^2$?

If we allow arbitrary polynomials over $x,y$ how does the maximal number of loops depend on the degree(s) of the polynomial?

Finally: How would one classify the curves according to their "loop structure" which considers the number of loops but possibly distinguishes between these curves which all have two loops:

[image]

And: **How could one systematically construct a polynomial** giving rise to a curve with a given loop structure, e.g. one of the three above.

---

(Do my tags make sense? Which ones would be better?)

Answer (score 1):

At a crossover point, $dy/dx=F_x/F_y$ is not defined so $F_x=F_y=0$.  An example with $mn$ crossing points is $F(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ where $g(x)$ has $m$ zeros and $h(y)$ has $n$ zeros.
An example for your middle sketch is
$$y^2 = -(x+1)^2x^2(x-1)$$
which has crossings at $(-1,0)$ and $(0,0)$.

Comment: Can I write your example in the form $F(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$ with $g(x)$ having two and $h(y)$ having one zero?

Comment: The exact form $g(x)h(y)=0$ is a grid of horizontal and vertical lines so is different from the other one.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I accidentally found in Marcel Bergers [Geometry Revealed](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/geometry-revealed-a-jacobs-ladder-to-modern-higher-geometry) (p. 287). It's about closed curves (while I had in mind open curves):

[image]